# Jquery with other libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, jquery

I am getting an error message as `element.dispatchEvent` is not a function. I am using jQuery with prototype in rails 3 application. In my layout file, I have added the js files as below

```
 javascript_include_tag 'jquery','jquery_ujs','prototype','shadowbox/shadowbox.js' 
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

I have also added `jQuery.noConflict` as above and used `jQuery` instead of `$` in jQuery functions. Any idea how to resolve this.?

In my another controller page action I have also mentioned the same thing as there are some js files which needs to be reloaded only for that particular page.

I am a newbie in js as well as rails also.

Comment: If at all possible, don't use multiple libraries at once. Do you really have a pressing reason to do this?

Comment: Yes.. I am using nicEdit in my application and nicEdit uses prototype. SO I cant avoid prototype..

Comment: Am I right on the above.?? I am confused now.. Does nicEdit work without using prototype. ??

Comment: There are other WYSIWYG editors out there - it may be less hassle finding one that works with jQuery than trying to get prototype and jQuery to work together.

Comment: I checked other editors also. But it seems there are some features which is lacking as compared to nicEdit. Main thing is that other editors dont have an HTML editor option to edit the html elements which nicEdit have.

Comment: If i am wrong, could you please suggest some editors where i can check and decide??

Comment: [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) is a very popular WYSIWYG editor and compatible with jQuery

Comment: Try including prototype in a separate `javascript_include_tag`, which is placed after script tag that calls `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Comment: I tried added it as seperate. But still it is getting error message:)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `jQuery.noConflict` **right** after src to the jQuery library

Comment: I have added it as above. That is enough right?? But still it is getting the above error message

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery.noConflict();` should be enough. Please check the code of the page in your browser so you can see when prototype is actually added.
You should have jQuery, then the .noConflict call, then prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding the 'no conflict' method, I do this instead (though both would probably be best):

I'll 'preset' my custom script page. Let's say my prediction is that I will use maybe 5 blocks of code in a page - this is how I preset my page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
 // use $ in here like normal! 
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});

etc. etc.
```

Notice this uses the jQuery object itself to pass as the callback function to the `.ready` method so you can once again use the `$` identifier within the functions.  I can rename it so their will never be a conflict, and I can use the `$` identifier within the function like I normally would. Hope that helps.